# Is there a way to know when the clipboard contents change with Delphi Firemonkey Clipboard services

Tags: delphi, clipboard, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi, FireMonkey, cross-platform for a desktop app, both Windows and MacOS. I want to have a memo control that contains the clipboard contents whenever it is text and is updated whenever the clipboard contents change. While I haven't done this in some time, I remember with the Win32 API, it was easy to do. Now I'm using the FMXClipboardServices and it doesn't seem like this is possible. There is a HasText method to determine whether the clipboard contents contains text but no way to hook into whenever that changes as far as I can tell.

Any ideas on how this can be solved? Writing native code for each platform?

Perhaps a good enough solution is just use a TTimer and check if the clipboard has text every second or so.

Comment: FMX has no clipboard monitoring capabilities.  You will have to resort to platform-specific APIs if you want to receive real-time notifications of data changes. At least on Windows, if you don't want/need a real-time detector, then you can use the timer approach with `GetClipboardSequenceNumber()` to detect if the clipboard has changed before you then check if the clipboard has text.  But you might miss a few updates here and there, if that is OK. Do you need to catch every possible change?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks. I don't need to catch every possible change.